# Spinning multiple nodes across multiple threads

Tags: ros, multithreading, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an application which dynamically spins up multiple nodes and needs to spin them (as they have subscribers).  Quick example, stolen from here: https://answers.ros.org/question/358343/rate-and-sleep-function-in-rclpy-library-for-ros2/?answer=358386#post-id-358386

```
import threading
import rclpy
rclpy.init()
node = rclpy.create_node('simple_node')
# Spin in a separate thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(node, ), daemon=True)
thread.start()
rate = node.create_rate(2)
try:
    while rclpy.ok():
        print('Help me body, you are my only hope')
        rate.sleep()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
rclpy.shutdown()
thread.join()
```

This example works totally fine and allows the spin to happen in a separate thread (which is what I want because my nodes do other threaded things as well).  The issue I get is when i add a second node and attempt to spin it, I get `ValueError: generator already executing`.  See this second example:

```
import threading
import rclpy
rclpy.init()
node = rclpy.create_node('simple_node')
node2 = rclpy.create_node('simpler_node')
# Spin in a separate thread
thread = threading.Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(node, ), daemon=True)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=rclpy.spin, args=(node2, ), daemon=True)
thread.start()
thread2.start()
rate = node.create_rate(2)
try:
    while rclpy.ok():
        print('Help me body, you are my only hope')
        rate.sleep()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
rclpy.shutdown()
thread.join()
thread2.join()
```

This results in an Exception being thrown in the second thread:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Help me body, you are my only hope
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 191, in spin
    executor.spin_once()
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 703, in spin_once
    handler, entity, node = self.wait_for_ready_callbacks(timeout_sec=timeout_sec)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 689, in wait_for_ready_callbacks
    return next(self._cb_iter)
ValueError: generator already executing
```

I realize there are other methods of composing multiple nodes but as I said, the nodes I'm building do a lot of other things in threads and are spun up dynamically by another process.  Is there some method I'm missing to tell `rclpy` to spin all nodes?  It seems the `rclpy.spin()` method *requires* the `node` argument.

edit: Quick addition.  The nodes I'm building inherit from `rclpy.node.Node` and I also attempted to `rclpy.spin_once(self)` from within those nodes in their main thread (thread that does other things) and I end up at the same `ValueError: generator already executing` error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377848/spinning-multiple-nodes-across-multiple-threads/) by [Chuck Claunch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3719/chuck-claunch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course I waited a while to post this after not finding an answer and now I have it.  I just needed to use a multi-threaded executor and spin that instead of spinning the nodes individually:

```
import threading
import rclpy
rclpy.init()
node = rclpy.create_node('simple_node')
node2 = rclpy.create_node('simpler_node')
executor = rclpy.executors.MultiThreadedExecutor()
executor.add_node(node)
executor.add_node(node2)
# Spin in a separate thread
executor_thread = threading.Thread(target=executor.spin, daemon=True)
executor_thread.start()
rate = node.create_rate(2)
try:
    while rclpy.ok():
        print('Help me body, you are my only hope')
        rate.sleep()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
rclpy.shutdown()
executor_thread.join()
```

---

Originally posted by [Chuck Claunch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3719/chuck-claunch/) with karma: 206 on 2021-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8